# After formation of the Grignard reagent, would it react with Et2O or methylpyridinium?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]I know that a Grignard would form, but im confused as to whether it would react with Et2O or with methylpyridinium. If it reacts with methylpyridinium, what would the mechanism be like?

Answer (score 8):

Grignard reactions are often carried out in diethyl ether as it is unreactive to them.

It is well established that organometallic reagents, including Grignard, react with Pyridine-*N*-oxide at the 2-position to give dihydropyridines or ring-opened products depending on work-up<sup>1</sup>.

Based on this reactivity and these references<sup>2,3</sup>, I think is likely that the benzyl Grignard will attack the 2-position of the pyridinium species. The actual product will depend on subsequent work-up, but the question setter probably expects to see the *N*-methyl-2-benzyl-dihydropyridine as product.

**References**

1. Hans Andersson, Xiaoyang Wang, Mikael Björklund, Roger Olsson, Fredrik Almqvist, "Reaction of pyridine *N*-oxides with Grignard reagents: a stereodefined synthesis of substituted dienal oximes," *Tetrahedron Letters* **2007**, *48(39)*, 6941-6944 DOI: [10.1016/j.tetlet.2007.07.161](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tetlet.2007.07.161)
2. Mikio Takeda, Arthur E. Jacobson, Ken Kanematsu, Everette L. May, "4-Methoxy-1-methylpyridinium iodide. Grignard products and transformations thereof," *Journal of Organic Chemistry* **1969**, *34(12)*, 4154-4157
   DOI: [10.1021/jo01264a087](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01264a087)
3. Edward V. White, "The Reactions of Organometallic Reagents with Pyridinium Salts," Ph.D. Dissertation;  University of New Hampshire, NH, 1968 ([pdf](https://scholars.unh.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1880&context=dissertation))